# php container can't connect to mongo container

Tags: php, mongodb, docker-compose

I setup docker compose to locally test my app and it seems that the app can't access the mongo instance even though I'm able to on Studio 3T.

this is what my docker-compose file looks like:

```yaml
services:
  web:
    image: php-app:latest
    ports:
      - '80:80'
    depends_on:
      - db
    networks:
      - code-network
  db:
    container_name: mongodb_4.4
    image: mongo:4.4
    environment:
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: demo
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: secret
    ports:
      - '27017:27017'
    networks:
      - code-network
    volumes:
      - mongodb_data_container:/data/db
volumes:
  mongodb_data_container: {}
networks:
  code-network:
    driver: bridge
```

this is what shows up in the docker console:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught MongoDB\\Driver\\Exception\\ConnectionTimeoutException: No suitable servers found (`serverSelectionTryOnce` set): [connection refused calling ismaster on '127.0.0.1:27017'] in /var/www/html/vendor/mongodb/mongodb/src/functions.php:431
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/html/vendor/mongodb/mongodb/src/functions.php(431): MongoDB\\Driver\\Manager->selectServer(Object(MongoDB\\Driver\\ReadPreference))
#1 /var/www/html/vendor/mongodb/mongodb/src/Collection.php(230): MongoDB\\select_server(Object(MongoDB\\Driver\\Manager), Array)
#2 /var/www/html/index.php(12): MongoDB\\Collection->aggregate(Array)
#3 {main}\n  thrown in /var/www/html/vendor/mongodb/mongodb/src/functions.php on line 431
```

I've tried adjusting my php code to connect using localhost and 127.0.0.1 and neither worked.

Comment: Connect to `db:27017`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you did not configure your MongoDB client yet, the default DSN is `mongodb://127.0.0.1/` (the local host), and it should be `mongodb://db/` (the db service you defined) in your case.

Read more about the constructor for MongoDB client:

- [MongoDB ligrary client](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-php-library/blob/master/src/Client.php#L106)
- [MongoDB extension manager](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mongodb-driver-manager.construct.php)